# If a cell contains specific text, copy the whole row & the next two rows to next sheet in excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I am very much new to VBA and i need some help.

We have 100's of records as shown in the image[image]

I would like to copy the row which has "Layer name" in it and the next two rows (Geometry & Feature Count) to the next sheet. I tried with the code mentioned here [if cell contains specific text, copy whole row + next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888464/if-cell-contains-specific-text-copy-whole-row-next-row) Of-course,changed all the '1's to '2'. But it didn't work. Any sort of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub layer()
j = 1
    For i = 1 To 100
      If Left(Cells(i, 1), 10) = "Layer name" Then
        For k = 0 To 2
          Sheets(2).Cells(j + k, 1) = Cells(i + k, 1)
        Next k
        j = j + 3
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

If Left(Cell.Value, 11) = "Layer name:" Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow + 2).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets(2).Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If lastRow > 1 Then lastRow = lastRow + 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(1).Select
End If
Next
End Sub
```